# Is there a keyboard shortcut for the method dropdown list in Visual Studio 2010's VB.NET code editor?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, there is a method dropdown list in VB code editor windows. This is highlighted in the screenshot below.

I would like to find out whether there is a default keyboard shortcut to access this list, or if such a keyboard binding can be manually set up (and if so, how)?

[image: Dropdown list in upper right corner of the VB.NET code editor window]

Comment: The closest I've found so far is the *Navigate To* dialog box, `[Ctrl]`+`[,]`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> is assigned as a default shortcut key to move the cursor to **Navigation Bar**. (***L.H.S*** is classes dropdown and ***R.H.S*** is methods dropdown.)

You can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to jump to methods dropdown.

The whole combination that you need is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I didn't even know that this bar was called "navigation bar", which made it all the harder finding that keystroke combination myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>F2</kbd>
and <kbd>Tab</kbd> can access that dropdown list. 
I was not able to find the direct short-cut for that dropdown list for long time.

Tools->Options->Environments->Keyboard can assign some short-cuts manually.

Answer (score 0):

Using AutoHotKey I was able to create a easier shortcut key: Windows + Shift + O

```
#+o::
  Send ^{F2}{Tab}{Tab}{Down}
Return
```

It immediately opens the dropdown too

Answer (score 0):

If you are generally looking for a way to jump to a specific member within the current class, there is also another way:

1. View.SynchronizeClassView will open the ClassView and directly select the class currently viewed in the Editor. The ClassView holds the member list in the bottom section.
2. Press Tab to jump to the member list (if not already selected)
3. Type the member name, press enter to jump to its definion